# JavaScript array recursion without generators

Tags: javascript, recursion

How would one solve the following problem without Generators? I came across something like this in a project I'm working on that requires deep iteration in pairs. I've only been able to solve it with Generators.

`nums` is a sample input. The input is an array of arbitrary length made up of integers and other such arrays of arbitrary depth.

Iterate over `nums` in pairs of [beforeNum, nextNum]. This means that
the first pair's first value should be `null` (`[null, 1]`). The second
pair should be `[1, 2]`, and so on. The final pair should be `[10, 11]`.

Ultimately, my actual goal was to be able to get the nth individual "atom", regardless of how many levels deep it is. For example, `get(nums, 6)` would be 7.

```
const nums = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6], 7], [8, 9, [10], 11]]];
```

**Edit** Figured it out with @hugomg's help. When I dove in, it turns out that the fact that I was actually implementing this with something much different than plain arrays was getting in my way. The solution's actually super straightforward: https://gist.github.com/jclem/fbd44c43cb175dbf880e

Comment: Is `nums` a sample input? Are inputs always a pair at any depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve your problem by doing a simple traversal over the tree by keeping a "prev" variable as we go along. Its just a matter of writing a simple recursion:

```js
function iterate(tree, onNum){

    var prev = null;

    function go(x, onNum){
       if(x instanceof Array){
         // If you are using a library that provides
         // an isArray function it can be more accurate than this.
         for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
             go(x[i], onNum);
         }
       }else{
         onNum(prev, x);
         prev = x;
       }
    }

    go(tree, onNum);
}

var myTree = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6], 7], [8, 9, [10], 11]]];
iterate(myTree, function(prev, curr){
    console.log(prev, curr);
});
```

No need to use generators here. Generators only help if you need to make your iterator into an external iterator that you can "pause". For example, if you need to iterate over two of these trees in parallel. For your current problem using an internal iterator and some recursion is fine.

Comment: Of course. I'm not sure why I had so much trouble with this, but this makes perfect sense. I'm curious how this could be modified to allow for fetching the nth pair.

Comment: Oh, it's just a simple countdown that's passed in to each iteration.

Comment: update a counter together with the "prev". To "get out" as soon as you find the result you want if more tricky. You can make all the functions return a boolean and exit immediately if a recursive call goes false or you can go for the hacky way and raise an exception

Comment: that said, it might be cleaner to refactor this into a flattening function that converts the tree into an array. Then all the operations you want become much easier

Comment: That said, what's difficult to get right is that fact that I essentially need to iterate over these pairs in a loop and do something each time. I'm actually using generators because I can just do this in a `for` loop using something like this: https://gist.github.com/jclem/358345e4c40d6cc7ea2b

Comment: generators are nice  because they play nice with "break" and "continue" syntax. If you don't need those then a callback-based internal iterator (like Array.forEach and the iterate I wrote) are just fine.

Comment: Re: "cleaner": In my use case, the function is being called many, many times per second and needs to hopefully not block the UI thread in a noticeable way as it's being called. You could argue, "find a way to not have the nesting at all", but the benefits outweigh the cost in my specific situation.

Comment: I do need `break`—I actually am frequently seeking the nth pair, and nothing beyond it. I could `throw`, but ugh.

Comment: The most performant way would be to use the recursive algo to flatten it into an array once and then cache that. Once you have an array you can find the nth element in O(1)

Comment: The array's internal structure is changing possibly many times per second.

Comment: That said, you can implement break with internal iterators, it just makes the code ugly :) And if you really want external iterators, the trick is to use a stack of indexes instead of recursion (this can be tricky to write though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77944/discussion-between-clem-and-hugomg).

Comment: This was my eventual solution, was *much* easier than I thought: https://gist.github.com/jclem/fbd44c43cb175dbf880e

Comment: you can turn those tail-recursive calls into a while loop, btw